# How to get variable from one window to another in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to get the variable that is currently assigned to "text" label(label_reduced_l) and use it for calculations in the next class / tkinter window. The variable counter_reduced and counter_regular after starting must be set to 0. Global variables do not cope with this task because, as I refer to it in another class, it has a value of 0 despite being increased by functions.
How can I change it to make it work?

From class:

```
class OrdinaryHourTicket(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller

        global counter_reduced
        global counter_regular
        counter_reduced = 0
        counter_regular = 0

        def on_click_up():
            global counter_reduced
            counter_reduced += 1
            label_reduced_l.configure(text=str(counter_reduced))

        def on_click_down():
            global counter_reduced
            if counter_reduced - 1 is not -1:
                counter_reduced -= 1
            label_reduced_l.configure(text=str(counter_reduced))

        label_reduced = tk.Label(self, text='Bilet Ulgowy: ', height=3, width=20, bg='gold',
                                 font=('Times New Roman', 20, 'bold'))
        label_reduced.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=70, pady=5, sticky='es')

        label_reduced_l = tk.Label(self, text=str(counter_reduced), height=3, width=5, bg='white',
                                   font=('Times New Roman', 20, 'bold'))
        label_reduced_l.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='es')

        btn_reduced_up = tk.Button(self, text="+", command=on_click_up, height=2, width=3,
                                   font=('Times New Roman', 30, 'bold'))
        btn_reduced_up.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=50, pady=5, sticky='ws')

        btn_reduced_down = tk.Button(self, text="-", command=on_click_down, height=2, width=3,
                                     font=('Times New Roman', 30, 'bold'))
        btn_reduced_down.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=150, pady=5, sticky="ws")
```

to class:

```
class ForPay(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        global counter_reduced, counter_regular

        label_pay_sum = tk.Label(self, text=(counter_reduced * 1.8 + counter_regular*3.8), height=3, width=5,
                                 bg='white', font=('Times New Roman', 20, 'bold'))
        label_pay_sum.grid(row=2, column=0, padx=5, pady=120, sticky='en')
```

Comment: Your `controller` should have a reference to the instance of `class OrdinaryHourTicket`. Access it with `controller.<ref to OrdinaryHourTicket>.label_reduced_l['text]`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve].